# Mongoose - go through object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Using mongoose on node.js I'm trying to find all games where player game.players.id equals the id I passed.

**Schema:**

```
var Game = mongoose.Schema({

    id: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    game: Object,
    isOnline: Boolean

});
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in this function but it returns empty array:

```
var specificGameStatistics = function (user, game) {
    var deferred = q.defer()
    Game.find({ "game.players.id" : user, "game.rules.gameType": game.gameType, "game.rules.quatro": game.quatro}, function(err, data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
////////////////////USAGE///////////////
var testGame = {rules: {gameType : 1, quatro : null}}
UsersCtrl.specificGameStatistics(data.id, testGame).then(function(userData) {
    console.log(userData);
});
```

And here is the example of the game already saved in database:

```
{
"isOnline" : true,
"game" : {
    "numberOfPlayers" : NumberInt("1"),
    "players" : [
        {
            "id" : "58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870",
            "name" : "PlayerName",
            "type" : NumberInt("1"),
            "avgStatistic" : "30.00",
            "numbersHit" : NumberInt("1"),
            "totalScore" : NumberInt("60"),
            ..............................
        }
    ], //there is more players here
    "rules" : {
        "gameType" : NumberInt("1"),
        "quatro" : null,
        "rounds" : NumberInt("1"),
    } // there is more in JSON object
    ...............................
"_id" : ObjectId("58aed4aeea20ecdf0c426838"),
"date" : ISODate("2017-02-23T13:25:18.284+01:00"),
"__v" : NumberInt("0")
}
```

I have tested the player ID to be equal and it is but still it returns empty array. **Test code:**

```
///////////TEST//////////////
console.log(data.id, "58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870");
if (data.id === "58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870") {console.log("this is true");}
var testGame = {rules: {gameType : 1, quatro : null}}
UsersCtrl.specificGameStatistics(data.id, testGame).then(function(userData) {
    console.log(userData);
});
//////////TEST///////////////
```

and it returns: 
58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870 58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870 
this is true 
[]

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Answer:** With help of Deividas Karžinauskas the solution is:

```
Game.where('game.players.id', user).where('game.rules.gameType', game.rules.gameType).find({}, function(err, data) { //, "game.rules.quatro": game.quatro
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the additional rules that you specify (`{gameType : 1, quatro : null}`), which do not exist in the player object (

```
{
    "id" : "58a2c0ecd8ba9f8602836870",
    "name" : "PlayerName",
    "type" : NumberInt("1"),
    "avgStatistic" : "30.00",
    "numbersHit" : NumberInt("1"),
    "totalScore" : NumberInt("60"),
    ..............................
}
```

). You can confirm this by simply looking for a game by id.

If you want to add these rules then you should find all games which match these rules and then look for the games of a specific player.

Comment: Oh yea that's true, wasn't thinking about that. So after i find all games then search all games by players.id. Thank You very much!

Comment: So I found all the games where player with some id was. That is all what I need, I will search now through all the games rules. It would be great if I could search for both at once as it is a big load of games in database it would be good. Will read doc and check back if it works.

Comment: Game.where('game.players.id', user).where('game.rules.gameType', game.rules.gameType).find({}, function(err, data) { //, "game.rules.quatro": game.quatro
        deferred.resolve(data);
 });