# Mongoose - different syntax

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Can someone tell me if this mongoose query can be simplified or writen more transparent. Please provide the example:

```
Game.where('game.players.id', user).where('game.rules.gameType', GameTypeEnum.x01)
    .where('game.rules.quatro', rules.quatro).where('game.rules.score', rules.score)
    .where('game.rules.parcheesi', rules.parcheesi).where('game.rules.runAndGun', rules.runAndGun)
    .where('game.rules.playOff', rules.playOff).where('game.rules.doubleIn', rules.doubleIn)
    .where('game.rules.doubleOut', rules.doubleOut).where('game.rules.masterOut', rules.masterOut)
    .where('game.rules.equalOption', rules.equalOption).where('game.rules.endOption', rules.endOption)
    .where('game.rules.teamRules', rules.teamRules).find({}, function(err, data) { 
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use the `find` query? Like so:

```
Game
  .find({
    'game.players.id': user,
    'game.rules.gameType': GameTypeEnum.x01,
    'game.rules.quatro': rules.quatro,
    'game.rules.score': rules.score,
    'game.rules.parcheesi': rules.parcheesi,
    'game.rules.runAndGun': rules.runAndGun,
    'game.rules.playOff': rules.playOff,
    'game.rules.doubleIn': rules.doubleIn,
    'game.rules.doubleOut': rules.doubleOut,
    'game.rules.masterOut': rules.masterOut,
    'game.rules.equalOption': rules.equalOption,
    'game.rules.endOption': rules.endOption,
    'game.rules.teamRules': rules.teamRules
  })
  .exec(function(error, data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
```

Comment: @AVoid I didn't get what is wrong, can you try rephrasing your comment?

Comment: In such query the first rule that is defined, in this case 'game.players.id', will be the main rule in which all other rules will be searched in. "search game.player.id where game.player.game.rules.gameType".

Comment: What "search game.player.id where game.player.game.rules.gameType" implies is that you are trying to retrieve the value of `game.player.id` which satisfy other queries.

Comment: Otherwise you can simply modify the query fields from `'game.rules.gameType'` to `'game.player.game.rules.gameType'`, etc.

Comment: Going by the other [SO question you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434718/mongoose-go-through-obj‌​ect), this solution seems to be fine. What issue are you facing?

Comment: I just asked is it possible to write this syntax better or more transparent

Comment: This is the only way there is that I know of. Let's see if others find something better. :)